# Spark SQL working on very large data set fails with file not found exception after 30 mins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

We have a Spark SQL working on very large data set (50 GB) this SQL does many aggregations. it fails after 30 mins saying "file not found". Is there any way we can ensure that code can be optimized to help reduce the network and CPU overhead?

We are working on HD insight cluster and we have increased timeout as well to ensure that it's not a network issue. Sample code below. Table A is created in parquet mode.

```
Agg_data_op = '''
SELECT trans_cd
    Sum ( b ),
    Sum (case … c)
    <50 aggregated fields>
From A group by trans_cd”
df_trans_mart = spark.sql(Agg_data_op)
df_trans_mart.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("df_core_mart")
```

Comment: Can you share the `file not found` error as well? If this is related to missing file in hive, you might want to go through this link :  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271008/skip-missing-files-from-hive-table-in-spark-to-avoid-filenotfoundexception]

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason of "No MCVE": _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.